# Why is 'continue' not skipping an iteration

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to use 'continue' to skip an iteration of a for loop if a condition is met.
The code:

```
s="MCMXCIV"
numeraldict = {
    "I":1,
    "V":5,
    "X":10,
    "L":50,
    "C":100,
    "D":500,
    "M":1000
}
num_list = [i for i in s]
num_val = 0
for x in range(0,len(num_list)-1):
    letter = num_list[x] & numeraldict.keys()
    num = numeraldict[num_list[x]]
    num_next = numeraldict[num_list[x+1]]
    if num < num_next:
        num = num_next - num
        num_val += num
        print("continued", x)
        continue
    print("not continued", x)
    num_val += num
    print(num_val)
num_val += num_next
print(num_val)
```

And the output I get is:

```
not continued 0
1000
continued 1
not continued 2
2900
continued 3
not continued 4
3090
continued 5
3099
```

When it says it is within the if condition, it doesnt skip an iteration.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the continue weren't working, as you claim, you would see "continued" and "not continued" output for the same number.  But that is not the case.

Comment: `continue` doesn't skip an iteration; it just skips the rest of the *current* iteration.

Comment: I see, so how do I get it to skip an iteration

Comment: Then you have to `continue` right at the start of your loop.

Comment: So cant come after an iteration that does something? I got a way around it by introducing a new variable which the code uses instead that I add +=2 instead but was still wondering if I can make it more efficient